# Java console log simultaneously to readLine without collisions

Tags: java, logging, console

I'm currently dealing with the following problem: 
I try to make a console input for a java application
that works with multiple threads. So while running the
software it happens sometimes, that a new line of log is
appearing while I'm writing to the readLine with a promt..
When that happens it looks like the following:
[Image of the Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zql98.png)
so it does stack the messages like in the image.. so here is the question:

**How can I keep the line and text I am writing to and log the text above it like in the example below?**
[Gif of the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b23UA.gif)

(Sorry for low quallity but you can guess what I mean)

As you can see my input stays at the bottom, is still editable and the lines do not stack

Thank you for some help, I am struggeling so much after trying Log4j, System.console, BufferedReaders and Scanner

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It was horrible complicated..
But here for the future:

```
class ConsoleThread implements Runnable {

private ConsoleReader reader;
private OutputStream output;

public ConsoleThread(OutputStream output, ConsoleReader reader) {
    this.output = output;
    this.reader = reader;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        String message;

        while (true) {

            message = LoggingQueue.getNextLogEvent();

            if(message == null) continue;

            reader.print(Ansi.ansi().eraseLine(Ansi.Erase.ALL).toString() + ConsoleReader.RESET_LINE);
            reader.flush();
            output.write((message + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes());
            output.flush();

            try {
                reader.drawLine();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                reader.getCursorBuffer().clear();
            }

            reader.flush();

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Controller.handleException(Thread.currentThread(), e);
    }

}
```

Using the ConsoleReader of jLine2 and jAnsi. The output stream is just System.out.

You just need a second thread which reads and you are done :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the threads competing for stdin/stdout.
In theory, that would imply some kind of mutex but, since you're using external libraries, it seems like too much trouble...

From your images, it seems that you're running a sort of server application that takes commands.
If that's the case, I recommend re-architecting to use two separate processes: one for the server part and one for the command prompt.
The two processes then communicate through a socket.
This allows you to make the command prompt single threaded or, at least, behave like a single threaded application, since it is only reacting to user commands.

This is what lots of applications, like Docker, Kubernetes or MySQL do.
In the case of Docker and Kubernetes, they expose full REST APIs on that socket so you can leverage libraries for that.